# Printing a range on the same line, and ending with a newline (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a homework assignment, and I managed to get most of the code (at least I think so).  But when I go to submit the assignment, my textbook wants my output to end in a newline.
Assignment: Write a program whose input is two integers. Output the first integer and subsequent increments of 5 as long as the value is less than or equal to the second integer.

Ex: If the input is:

-15
10
the output is:

-15 -10 -5 0 5 10
Ex: If the second integer is less than the first as in:

20
5
the output is:

Second integer can't be less than the first.

My code:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())

if y >= x:
    for i in range(x, y+1, 5,):
        print(i, end=' ')
else:
    print('Second integer can\'t be less than the first.')
```

[This is where my problem lies.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRvei.png)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just add a `print()` outside your `for` loop

Answer (score 2):

Add `print()` after the loop:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())

if y >= x:
    for i in range(x, y+1, 5,):
        print(i, end=' ')
    print()
else:
    print('Second integer can\'t be less than the first.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `print('\n')` after your loop

```py
if y >= x:
    for i in range(x, y+1, 5,):
        print(i, end=' ')
    print('\n')
```

Comment: When I do that, it treats it as if I added an extra newline.  It's very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Add the print() on the same level as the for statement

```
for i in range(x, y+1, 5,):
    print(i, end=' ')
    
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks shanooonooo.
Your code helped with mine.

```
''' Type your code here. '''
num1 = int(input())
num2 = int(input())


if num1 <= num2:
    while num1 <= num2:
        print(num1, end=' ')
        num1 += 5
    print()
else:
    print('Second integer can\'t be less than the first.')
```